# Understanding the regex from a jQuery get url parameter function

Tags: jquery, regex

I have searched stack overflow for a Javascript solution (in the jQuery library) to get the URL parameter.

I have this function which does it smoothly:

```
// get the firstname value from the myurl - http://mysite.com?firstname=dany&lastname=dughy

var myurl = $("#gup").data("url");
var name = "firstname";

function gup(name, myurl) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec(myurl);
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

I understand how it works, you set a regex and than execute that regex and retrieve the results in an array.

**Can someome please explain the regex to me? I can't seem to understand it.**

Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the function with `gup("NAME","http://domain.com?NAME=value&name2=value2")`.

```
function gup(name, myurl) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
```

This line escapes square brakets so it works nicely in the regex query, making `"[]"` into `"\\\[\\\]"`.

```
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
```

Now the name is parsed to work in the regex. It will look like `"[\\?&]NAME=([^&#]*)"`.

`"[\\?&]"` means find either `?` or `&`. Because `?` is a special character, to match a `?` in text you need to escape it like `\?`, so this regex would become `[\?&]` but in javascript strings you need to escape the `\` again. So `[\?&]` becomes `"[\\?&]"` in a string.

`=([^&#]*)` matches a literal `=` followed by any character except an `&` or `#`.

```
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec(myurl);
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
```

Returns the captured group, which is at position 1. Position 0 is the whole match.

```
}
```

Function call returns `value`

Comment: I really did not know you had to escape strings again in JS (which confused me) and I definitely need to work some more on practical regexes. You opened a great path for me. Ty!

Comment: Won't `[\\?&]` find \, `?` or `&` though? Regexp tester gives me this: http://i.imgur.com/UM0Pcok.png

Comment: @eithed yes, it would if it were plain regex but it is in a JS string, so you need to escape the `\ ` that is used for escaping the `?`

Comment: @eithed, you are testing it incorrectly. The point is being in a JS string. This shows what happens to a JS string: `new RegExp("[\\?&]")`. Then execute this: `"i\\love?programming&too".replace(/[\?&]/gi,"")`. Besides, the `\ ` is not used as a separator in URLs so the point is mute.

Comment: @Gerard Sexton, ah, yes, now I know what you mean. Thank you for explanation and your time!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you're searching for firstname, then the regexp becomes: `[\\?&]firstname=([^&#]*)`. Now, what it means is: `[\\?&]` search for any of characters `\`, `?` or `&` that has `firstname=` afterwards, and `[^&#]*` = anything but `&` or `#` characters afterwards

Comment: Ty very much for answering. I believe Gerard's answer is more comprehensive; this is why I have accepted it.

Comment: No worries :) Regexpes are funny like that. I think though that there's a small mistake in the explanation of `[\\?&]`, as it means \, `?` or `&` (well, at least I think it does :D). Let me put this under his answer as a comment.